# Nano: keyboard shortcut to move cursor to the beginning of the next empty line?

Tags: text-processing, editors, nano

In `nano` text editor: what is the keyboard shortcut to move cursor to the beginning of the next empty line? If there is no default one, then what would be the right one?

Comment: Probably `↓`, then `Home`. If this is too "slow" for you, consider switching to a more advanced editor (such as `vi`/`vim`).

Comment: The whole point of nano is that it is simple with no complex shortcuts to learn.  If you want shortcuts, get a better editor.

Comment: ctrl+n also does this in nano line in emacs. @user10489 i completely disagree, nano has lots of keyboard shortcuts and you can remap them.